# Report with Pivot Tables like in Excel using Python

Tags: python, excel, numpy, pandas

I have data

```
ID,"address","used_at","active_seconds","pageviews"
0a1d796327284ebb443f71d85cb37db9,"vk.com",2016-01-29 22:10:52,3804,115
0a1d796327284ebb443f71d85cb37db9,"2gis.ru",2016-01-29 22:48:52,214,24
0a1d796327284ebb443f71d85cb37db9,"yandex.ru",2016-01-29 22:14:30,4,2
0a1d796327284ebb443f71d85cb37db9,"worldoftanks.ru",2016-01-29 22:10:30,41,2
```

But it so large and `Excel` can't open it.
I need to divide all time to different week and print result to every `id` to every `address`.
It should look like

```
ID                                 vk.com              2gis.ru             yandex.ru

0a1d796327284ebb443f71d85cb37db9     23                     40                  56
465a3fc01a62fd89a8094abdaccdcc99      0                     100                 45
...
```

I count it to all time

```
data = pd.read_csv("desktop-visits-dnp.csv")
group = data.groupby(['ID', 'address']).active_seconds.sum()
```

But I need to divide it to weeks

But I don't have many skills with `python` and don't know have can I deside this task

Comment: what do you mean saying: `to divide all time to different week`?

Comment: I need to get different table to different week. For example 25.01 - 31.01, 1.02 - 07.02

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code creates a sum of `active_seconds` per `ID` and `week`.

First, producing some sample data similar to yours:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
ids = [''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits) for _ in range(16)]) for i in range(10)]
addresses = [''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(10)]) for i in range(10)]
df['ID'] = np.random.choice(ids, size=10000)
df['address'] = np.random.choice(addresses, size=10000)
df['active_seconds'] = np.random.randint(0, 100, 10000)

df['used_at'] = pd.date_range(start=datetime(2016, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), freq='H', periods=10000)
```

Now set `used_at`, `ID` and `address` to `index` to `unstack()` the latter, which puts `address` into the columns with `active_seconds` as values.

```
df = df.set_index(['used_at', 'ID', 'address']).unstack().loc[:, 'active_seconds'].reset_index('ID')
```

Next, group by `ID`, `resample` on a weekly basis while summing all values within each interval, and reset `ID` as column instead of index:

```
df = df.groupby('ID').resample('W', how='sum').reset_index('ID')
```

to get weekly usage per `ID` and `address`:

```
df.head()

address                   ID  afgpxizbum  cihchvzttw  dguznssmbi  irpvqtmuva  \
used_at                                                                        
2016-01-03  06y2myiclyb2s4hr         NaN         NaN         NaN        19.0   
2016-01-10  06y2myiclyb2s4hr        57.0        15.0        66.0         NaN   
2016-01-17  06y2myiclyb2s4hr        13.0       144.0       152.0       139.0   
2016-01-24  06y2myiclyb2s4hr       186.0       112.0         NaN         NaN   
2016-01-31  06y2myiclyb2s4hr        15.0        68.0       128.0        63.0   

address     otlkynddwv  ptzzhghnfl  rgwbuevvez  tgvbvfibaf  toimlivump  \
used_at                                                                  
2016-01-03        30.0         NaN         NaN        50.0         NaN   
2016-01-10        59.0        28.0         NaN         NaN       214.0   
2016-01-17       106.0        26.0       179.0        62.0        69.0   
2016-01-24        87.0        10.0       130.0       264.0         7.0   
2016-01-31       144.0         NaN       215.0         NaN       208.0   

address     uwsdzqyudi  
used_at                 
2016-01-03        99.0  
2016-01-10       235.0  
2016-01-17       128.0  
2016-01-24        85.0  
2016-01-31        60.0
```

Now you can `group_by` week in the index, iterate over the result and save to index.

```
for week, data in df.groupby(level=0):
    data.to_excel('{}.xlsx'.format(week))
```

Comment: I have memory error. How can I to save this data to `excel` file? And I need to save different week to different file. for example data with `2016-01-03` to one file, `2016-01-10` to other file etc.

Comment: See update for saving to excel on a weekly basis. If you get a memory error, you may want to read in your data as chunks and process in parts and aggregate several weekly files in a second step.